# Is it portable to indent the argument to sed's 'i\' command?

Tags: sed, posix, portability

I was under the impression from the [POSIX specs for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) that it is necessary to left-align the text on the line following the `i\` command, unless you want leading whitespace in the output.

A quick test on my Mac (using BSD sed) shows that perhaps this is *not* necessary:

```
$ cat test.sed 
#!/bin/sed -f
i\
      This line starts with spaces.
$ echo some text | sed -f test.sed
This line starts with spaces.
some text
$
```

However, I can't seem to find this documented anywhere.  It's not in the POSIX specs, and it's not even in `sed`'s man page on my system.

**Can I rely on this behavior in `sed` scripts which I want to be portable?**  How portable is it?

(Is it documented *anywhere?*)

---

(Bonus question: Is it even possible to force `sed` to insert whitespace at the beginning of a fixed line passed to `i\`?)

Comment: @don_crissti, you are correct, that works.  (Only the first blank needs to be escaped.)  And I see that this agrees with POSIX specs: *"The argument* text *shall consist of one or more lines. Each embedded `<newline>` in the text shall be preceded by a `<backslash>`. Other `<backslash>` characters in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but your script will be portable as long as you escape any leading blank. Why ? Because some `sed`s strip blank characters from text lines and the only way to avoid that is to escape the leading blank, as these manual pages dating back from the last century explain: [1](http://holt.oso.chalmers.se/hgs/unix.man/sed.html), [2](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/dv/hats/cats/stations/qnxman/sed.html), [3](https://swtch.com/plan9port/man/man1/sed.html)
The same goes for `BSD` `sed` (`OSX` just copied the code, it's not their extension) and if you check the archives and read the [`man` page from `BSD 2.11`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=2.11%20BSD&arch=default&format=html) it's pretty clear:

> *(1)i\*
>   *text*
>   .......
>   An argument denoted *text* consists of one or more lines, all but the
>   last of which end with `'\'` to hide the newline.  Backslashes in text
>   are treated like backslashes in the replacement string of an `'s'`
>   command, and may be used to protect initial blanks and tabs against
>   the stripping that is done on every script line.

Now, where is this documented in the POSIX spec ? It only says

> The argument text shall consist of one or more lines. Each embedded
>   <newline> in the text shall be preceded by a  <backslash>. Other
>    <backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the following
>   character shall be treated literally.

and if you scroll down under *RATIONALE* it says

> The requirements for acceptance of  <blank> and  <space> characters in
>   command lines has been made more explicit than in early proposals to
>   describe clearly the historical practice and to remove confusion about
>   the phrase "protect initial blanks [sic] and tabs from the stripping
>   that is done on every script line" that appears in much of the
>   historical documentation of the sed utility description of text. (Not
>   all implementations are known to have stripped  <blank> characters from
>   text lines, although they all have allowed leading  <blank> characters
>   preceding the address on a command line.)

Since the part with *"backslashes may be used to"* was not included in that quote, the remaining phrase *"protect initial blanks..."* doesn't make any sense...<sup>1</sup>

---

Anyway, to sum up: some implementations did (and some still do) strip blanks from text lines. However, since the POSIX spec to which all implementations should comply says

> Other <backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the
>   following character shall be treated literally.

we can conclude that the portable way to indent the lines in the text-to-be-inserted is by escaping the leading blank on each of those lines.

---

<sup>1: I also don't understand why `OSX`/`BSD` people have changed the entire paragraph in the `man` page without altering the source code - you get the same behavior as before but the man section that documents this stuff is no longer there.</sup>

Comment: The _Other <backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally_ is not true of GNU `sed` (even with POSIXLY_CORRECT) where sequences like `\n` are expanded.

Answer (score 3):

It's OSX `sed` extension, not standard behavior. You can see [this link, in function `compile_text`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-18/sed/compile.c):

```
/*
 * Compile the text following an a or i command.
 */
static char *
compile_text()
{
    int asize, size;
    char *text, *p, *op, *s;
    char lbuf[_POSIX2_LINE_MAX + 1];

    asize = 2 * _POSIX2_LINE_MAX + 1;
    text = xmalloc(asize);
    size = 0;
    while (cu_fgets(lbuf, sizeof(lbuf))) {
        op = s = text + size;
        p = lbuf;
        EATSPACE();
        for (; *p; p++) {
            if (*p == '\\')
                p++;
            *s++ = *p;
        }
        size
```

They ate spaces using `EATSPACE` macro.

In FreeBSD `sed`, which can incorrectly treat `\` as line continuation characters when using `a`, `i`, `c`, the behavior is weirder. In my FreeBSD 9.3:

```
$ echo 1 | sed -e 'i\ 1'
": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

but:

```
$ echo 1 | sed -e 'i\
 2'
2
1
```

works, and it also eats spaces.

GNU `sed`, the heirloom `sed` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Wow, so it looks like if you want to be certain of what you are getting in a portable `sed` script, just never ever use leading spaces after an `i` or an `a` command.

Answer (score 2):

[*Cuonglm* gave the best answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312583/165517), but for the record here's what *GNU* `sed` does:

```
echo foo | sed 'i\
     This line starts with spaces.'
```

Output:

```
     This line starts with spaces.
foo
```