# One-liner to insert a new line of text (literally a regex, thus many to be escaped characters) in a configuration file before a specific string?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sed, macintosh

I do wish to modify a Mac OS X sandbox file via a one-line (copy and paste) command, by inserting a new line — containing a regex — after a line that contains a specific string (also being a regex pattern).

The file to edit requires root rights and is located at `/usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb`.

Both search and append lines contain loads of usually to be escaped characters because these are regex-es and containing paths.

## Search for line containing

```
(regex #"^/private/var/clamav/")
```

Note: the string is preceded with tabs in one case.

## Insert this line before the match

```
    (regex #"^/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent\$")
```

Note: this to be inserted new-line-string should be prepended with one tab (`\t`).

## My failing try

```
sudo sed -i '' -e $'/(regex #"\^\/private\/var\/clamav\/")/a \t(regex #"\^\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/TrustEvaluationAgent\.framework\/Versions\/A\/TrustEvaluationAgent\\\$")' /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb
sed: 1: "/(regex #"\^\/private\/ ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

## Question

How to fix the above `sed` command

**or**

supply a better readable and working alternative that can be used to copy from a website and paste into the Mac OS X terminal (bash) to extend this sandbox configuration file?

Comment: 1) You need `i` to insert before the match, not `a`. 2) Avoid picket fence (i.e. use a delimiter like `|` - keep in mind that in a context address you have to escape the first one). 3) With `i` or `a` you only need to escape backslashes and the end of lines (except the last one):  `sed -e '\|(regex #"^/private/var/clamav/")|i\' -e '    (regex #"^/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent\\$")'` the leading space in the second `e`xpression is a literal tab.

Comment: **Don't use `-i ''` until you're *sure* your command is correct.**  `-i` is for in-place editing, not for testing your command.  :)

Comment: @don_crissti, [macOS Sed will strip out that leading tab character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312583/135943), so that command won't work exactly as requested.

Comment: see if this works out.. `seq 4 | sed '/3/ s/.*/    abc\n&/'` ... replace `/3/` with appropriate search pattern and `    abc` with line to insert before matching line

Comment: @Wildcard - yeah, I left a comment about this on your Q - I still think it's doable with `i` or `a` but anyway, even if it wasn't, imo it's still easier to run `sed '\|(regex #"^/private/var/clamav/")|s|^| (regex #"^/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.fr‌​amework/Versions/A/T‌​rustEvaluationAgent\‌​\$")\n&|'` (replacing the `n` in `\n` with a literal newline) - similar to what _Sundeep_ suggests above - than doing all that escaping with `awk`...

Comment: @don_crissti Where is the starting <tab>-character (before `regex(…`)  in your `sed` command?

Comment: @don_crissti When I paste the command containing the literal tab to a terminal application, the command becomes mixed up. That is the reason why I can't use your `sed` solution.

Comment: Ok then don't paste it, simply type it... and use `Ctrl`+`V` then `TAB` to insert a literal tab when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do this with macOS Sed,** because it strips leading whitespace from the lines that you are inserting.

- [Is it portable to indent the argument to sed's 'i\' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312579/135943)

## Using Awk:

```
awk '/\(regex #"\^\/private\/var\/clamav\/"\)/ {print "\t(regex #\"^/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent\$\")"}; {print}' /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb > ~/temp-clamd.sb
```

Note that I've redirected the output to `~/temp-clamd.sb` rather than editing the file in place (which is tricky or impossible with BSD Awk).

Next you can check that the changes are as you expect with:

```
diff /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb ~/temp-clamd.sb
```

If everything is correct, overwrite the contents of the original file with the modified copy (**don't** use `mv`, which would change the inode, permissions, owner):

```
cat ~/temp-clamd.sb | sudo tee /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb
```

Comment: The `awk` result is that the `diff` is not able to find any difference between /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb and ~/temp-clamd.sb. The `sed` is ok, except for the minor issue that the <tab> `\t` is not inserted. The new line directly starts with `(regex`.

Comment: @ProBackup, see edit re Sed result.  I got it on the Awk result; are you certain that line has no trailing whitespace or anything similar?  Compare the results of `grep -F "(regex #\"^/private/var/clamav/\")" /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb` and `grep -xF "(regex #\"^/private/var/clamav/\")" /usr/share/sandbox/clamd.sb`; are they the same?  (Do they both output a line?)

Comment: The first `grep -F` does output 1 line. The second `grep -xF` does not output a line. There doesn't seem to be a trailing whitespace character.

Comment: @ProBackup, that means the line has leading or trailing space.  (The `-F` means "fixed string comparison" rather than regex, and `-x` limits it to whole line matches.)  Tweak the expression until it shows up with `-xF` as well as `-F`, and then drop that exact string into the Awk equality test.  It's hard to tell from your comment formatting, but possibly `" (regex #\"^/private/var/clamav/\")"` is what you need (note the leading space at the beginning).

Comment: @mikeserv, not helpful.  An Awk string equality check should work perfectly fine.  The only trick is to ensure we have the *full* line in the equality check.

Comment: @Wildcard My goal is to search for a line **containing** (though I can live with _ending in_) the text `(regex #"^/private/var/clamav/")`

Comment: @ProBackup, in that case you *do* need to use a regex, not a string equality check.  But you can't use macOS Sed to insert or append lines with leading whitespace, so see my new edit for how to do this with Awk.